# How to fscaf unknown number of integers into an array

Tags: c, arrays, integer, scanf

I am reading a text file from standard input that have the following form:

**5**

**4** **7** **9** **2** **1**

where the first row is the size of the array I want to create each time and in the second row are the elements

So far I have this

```
int main()
{
  int N;
  int i;
  FILE *fp;
  const char *mode="r";
  fp=fopen("input.txt", "r");

  if((fp=fopen("input.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file %s\n");
    return -1;
  }

  fscanf(fp, "%d", &N);

  int a[N];
  int n;

  while (fscanf(fp, "%d %n", &a[i], &n) == 1){
    i++;
    fp += n;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

It reads the file but it doesnt store the correct values

Comment: why are you not using any c++ when this is supposed to be c++?

Comment: coincidentally your code is valid C but not valid C++. `int a[N];` is a variable lenght array, C has them, C++ not

Comment: As these two have pointed out. There is no C++ here. This is C. Consider changing your tag to reflect the correct language.

Comment: You are using C++, so use `getline()` to read an entire line of values, then create a `stringstream ss (line)` and use `>>` to read `int` values from the stringstream. (if it is just an unknown number of `int` in a single line, skip the stringstream). *Validate* each read.

Comment: @Sailanarmo if it is compiled with a c++ compiler then it is c++ by definition, only OP can know what language they are targeting

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am not sure I agree with that. C and C++ are two different languages. C++ can compile C but to say C code suddenly becomes C++ code just because you compile it with a C++ compiler doesn't make it C++ code.

Comment: 30 years ago C++ was a superset of C. (now they are completely different animals)

Comment: @Sailanarmo no. C++ cannot compile C. There is a small subset that is correct code in both and apart from the VLA (which exists in gcc as non-standard extension also in C++) this code belongs to that subset afaik, hence only OP can know what they use to compile it

Comment: There is a subset that is correct in both and **only a subset of that subset has the same *behaviour* in both**.

Comment: This is neither nor, it is not proper standard C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you cannot use containers from STL, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), you will make like much easier and less error prone by using them. Here, while you can read the first value `N`, it isn't needed when you use a `std::vector` for storage. The STL containers handle required storage automatically, so all you really care about is reading the actual data values from the file and then using the `.push_back()` member function to add the values to your vector.

Do not *Hardcode Filenames* in your code. That is what the arguments to `int main (int argc, char **argv)` are for (or you can take the filename as input). For example you could do:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int N, tmp;             /* int N and temporary int to use filling vector */
    std::vector<int> v;     /* vector of int */

    if (argc < 2) { /* valdate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open file */

    if (!f.good()) {    /* validate file open */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

No need to hardcode your filename, just pass it as an argument to `main()`.

With your file open, in its simplest form, you can simply use the overloaded `>>` stream operator to read values from your file. You must ***validate*** every read to ensure a stray non-digit character does cause a matching failure and set a failed stream state on your input stream. For example to check if the read of `N` is good (not bad here), you could do:

```
    if (!(f >> N)) {    /* read/validate N */
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input - N.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Since the intent was to exit unless the read was good, the `!(f >> N)` form was used. (this also reduces the levels of indention you build into your code). You could have done:

```
    if (f >> N) {    /* read/validate N */
        /* rest of your code goes here on good read */
    }
```

The validation is the same, but in the first case we exit on a failure to read `N`, in the second, we just do not enter the block enclosing the rest of our code (which is now shifted with one more layer of indention to the right...)

Reading the rest of the values and filling your vector is just a matter of reading into your temporary values `tmp` in the same manner and then after confirming a good read, you simply add the value to your vector using the `.push_back()` member function, e.g.

```
    while (f >> tmp)    /* read remaining int values into vector v */
        v.push_back(tmp);
```

(**note:** reading numeric values all *whitespace* is ignored. That means whether you have 1-line or 1000-lines of integer values remaining in the file -- all will be read into your vector. All `'\n'` are simply ignored since a `'\n'` is *whitespace*. This is where you use `getline()` and a `std::stringstream` if you need to read only values in a single line)

Reading the first `N` is only good for comparing with the `.size()` of the vector which you can now use to confirm you have read `N` values into your vector, e.g.

```
    if (v.size() != (size_t)N) {    /* valdate .size() == N */
        std::cerr << "error: number read does not equal N.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

You can do whatever you like with the values in your vector `v`. Here they are simply output using a *range-based* for loop and repurposing `tmp` as a counter to output the index as well:

```
    tmp = 0;
    for (auto& n : v)   /* loop over all values in v outputting */
        std::cout << "v[" << tmp++ << "] : " << n << '\n';
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int N, tmp;             /* int N and temporary int to use filling vector */
    std::vector<int> v;     /* vector of int */

    if (argc < 2) { /* valdate 1 argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open file */

    if (!f.good()) {    /* validate file open */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(f >> N)) {    /* read/validate N */
        std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input - N.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (f >> tmp)    /* read remaining int values into vector v */
        v.push_back(tmp);

    if (v.size() != (size_t)N) {    /* valdate .size() == N */
        std::cerr << "error: number read does not equal N.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    tmp = 0;
    for (auto& n : v)   /* loop over all values in v outputting */
        std::cout << "v[" << tmp++ << "] : " << n << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/nint.txt`, you would use the program as follows generating the following output:

```
$ ./bin/readnint dat/nint.txt
v[0] : 4
v[1] : 7
v[2] : 9
v[3] : 2
v[4] : 1
```

Moral of the story -- *Do Not Use* `scanf`. It is so full of pitfalls for the new C/C++ programmer, and its improper use generates so many questions on this site it would be tantamount to *programming-malpractice* to suggest a `scanf` solution. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.